# Django filters PDF export

Tags: python, django, export, django-filters

I'm trying to export my django-filters query to PDF, but I don't know how to call the function. Actually I have the follow views.py:

```
def searchClient (request):
    clientFilter = ClientFilter(request.GET, queryset=Client.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    clients_list = clientFilter.qs

    paginated_filtered_clients_list = Paginator(clients_list, settings.ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    clients_list = paginated_filtered_clients_list.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request,'agenda/searchClient.html', {'clients_list': clients_list, 'clientFilter': clientFilter})

def getsearchedClientsAsPDF (request):
    clientFilter = ClientFilter(request.GET, queryset=Client.objects.all().order_by('id'))
    clients_list = clientFilter.qs

    pdf_file = generateTablePDF('Clients', clients_list)

    # Download the pdf file
    return FileResponse(pdf_file, as_attachment=True, filename='Clients.pdf')
```

And this for the HTML.

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn" href="{% searchClient 1 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}" title="Bootstrap 3 themes generator">
<a class="btn btn-info btn" href ="{% url 'getsearchedClientsAsPDF' %}" title="Bootstrap 3 themes generator">Print</a>
```

Basicly, my problem it's thath I can't pass the search request to my **getsearchedClientsAsPDF** view.

Maybe, there are another way, but i don't know how to resolve it.
All help its wecome.

Answer (score 0):

Finnally I found my own answer.

Put attention to href and how to build.

```
{% url 'searchClient' %}?{% searchClient 1 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}
```

I tried times before, but I forgot the ? character.